# SQL WP DB Correct Migration

Tags: wordpress, mysqli, database-migration

I have moved my WP dynamic project from a ftp server to localhost MAMP server. Everything was transferred perfectly, except values inside WP_POST table, GUID column. For Example: http://www.rinatgontar.com/?page_id=2 should change to: http://localhost:8888/?page_id=2 .
Whats the correct SQL query that can do it ?
Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: You meen export to text editor replace and then import it back ?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. :-) I'll add it to my answer so it can help other people too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a text editor to do a global search and replace in the SQL file.

Export the entire database or all tables to a `.sql` file using PhpMyAdmin or whatever tool you like. Open the file in your favorite text editor.

First search for `http://www.rinatgontar.com` and replace all occurrences with `http://localhost:8888`

Then search and replace `www.rinatgontar.com` with `localhost:8888`

Then if it occurs replace `rinatgontar.com` with `localhost:8888`

Import the `.sql` file back. If you exported all tables instead of the entire database you should first delete all tables before you import the file back.

That should do it.